# Which parts of Windows GUI stack are in kernel?

Tags: windows, gdi, wdk, user32

Windows NT 4 introduced Win32k.sys which if I remember correctly is mostly kernel-side GDI but also has some windowing functions.

What is the modern (post-Vista) state of Windows kernel-side GUI support? Were there any movements to make it faster and/or more robust?

What is the mechanism behind "display driver stopped responding and has recovered"?

Note that GDI is a legacy codepath now, so I'm asking specifically about the recent advancements, such as the kernel support needed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager. A lot of GUI these days are WPF and UWP which I suppose use different codepaths and supported by new "post-GDI" features.

Comment: [GDI from the Driver's Perspective](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/gdi-from-the-driver-s-perspective)?

Comment: Yes, but it only covers GDI and for is for pre-WDDM graphics stack of Windows 2000. I added a paragraph to clarify

Comment: The error message does not have anything to do with the question.  Video drivers were by far the largest source of blue-screen crashes.  Pretty unsubtle too, iirc it was above the 90% bracket.  Had my own fair share of it over the years.  They did something about it around a decade ago, they made it a recoverable mishap.  You do get a notification about the weirdo flashing and whatnot, that's what you saw.  I still get them as well, very occasionally, from a stock Intel driver that just about everybody uses.  Driver updates don't get pushed very aggressively btw.

Comment: The underlying technical kernel features are pretty relevant. It's not about the message, but about how the recovery works in the kernel. And display driver recovery is definitely a part of GUI support in kernel :)